# Не создается проект VS 2008 C#

Tags: visual-studio

При попытке создать проект выдает сообщение: Чтобы создать экземпляр проекта свойство Engine.BinPath должно указывать на место на диске, где установлена программа MSBuild. Это необходимо для вычисления $(MSBuildBinPath). Установлена Windows 7 32bit. Что делать чтобы исправить это, как задать это свойство?

Comment: А зачем такую древнюю студию запускать? Они же все более менее обратносовместимы.

Comment: У меня древний ноутбук, так что думаю что новые будут лагать. К тому же новые очень много места занимают на диске.

Comment: На сколько древний? У меня на работе стоит комп 2010 года с 2-ух ядерным Core I5 первого поколения и студия 2019 года прекрасно работает. Так же есть альтернативы: Можно поставить легковесный Visual Studio Code. Если вы поставить Vs2008 года, то потеряете много фич современной редакции языка.

Comment: Проц одноядерный атом n435 и 2 гига озу

Comment: Печалька. Попробуйте Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 0):

Возможно дистрибутив битый. Возможно проблема с жестким диском.

Попробуйте скачать и поставить что-нибудь из этого [обсуждения](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108102/download-and-install-visual-studio-2008).

Я рекомендую 2015 студию, не намного больше и выглядит уже по современному (и полностью поддерживает классический .NET). Можно посмотреть ссылку на скачивание из этой [статьи](http://blogs.bukutamudigital.com/2016/06/28/visual-studio-2015-update-3-offline-installer/).

Если нужен .NET Core и любите минимализм и консоль, то поставьте небольшой редактор [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) и установите в нем [расширение](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode) для C#.

А вобще попробуйте зайти на [офицальный сайт](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&rel=16) и скачать последнюю доступную версию (она бесплатная). Не пойдет или не понравится скорость работы, то удалите.

Кстати, на компьютер можно ставить разные версии Visual Studio и они не будут конфликтовать друг с другом.